# problems to separate long table and to adjust it to text width

Tags: longtable, longtabu

I have the next long table that should be splitted into two pages and also since it has 11 columns, it should be adjusted to fit the text width. I have tried with several packages, and the closest that I have so far is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\caption{$E_{T}$ values}
\bigskip
\label{tab:table8}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|l|l|ccccccccc|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Percent Upgrade}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Length 
(mi)}} &  \multicolumn{9}{l|}{\textbf{\underline{Proportion of Trucks and 
Buses}}} \\
\cline{3-11}
& & 2\% & 4\% & 5\% & 6\% & 8 \% & 10 \% & 15 \% & 20 \% & 25\% \\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} 
{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ 
\hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot


\hline
$\leq 2$ & All & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{$>2-3$} & $ > 0.00 - 0.25$  & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 
1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& $>0.25 - 0.50$ & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& $> 0.50 - 0.75$ & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& $> 0.75 - 1.00$ & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& $> 1.00 - 1.50$ & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
& $> 1.50$ & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{$>3-4$} & $> 0.00 - 0.25$  & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 
1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& $>0.25 - 0.50$ & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& $> 0.50 - 0.75$ & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
& $> 0.75 - 1.00$ & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
& $> 1.00 - 1.50$ & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
& $> 1.50$ & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{$>4-5$} & $> 0.00 - 0.25$  & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 
1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& $>0.25 - 0.50$ & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
& $> 0.50 - 0.75$ & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
& $> 0.75 - 1.00$ & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
& $> 1.00$ & 5.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{$>5-6$} & $> 0.00 - 0.25$  & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 
1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& $>0.25 - 0.50$ & 4.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
& $> 0.30 - 0.50$ & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
& $> 0.50 - 0.75$ & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
& $> 0.75 - 1.00$ & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
& $> 1.00$ & 6.0 & 5.0 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{$>6$} & $> 0.00 - 0.25$  & 4.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 
& 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.0 \\
& $>0.25 - 0.50$ & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
& $> 0.30 - 0.50$ & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
& $> 0.50 - 0.75$ & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
& $> 0.75 - 1.00$ & 6.0 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 \\
& $> 1.00$ & 7.0 & 6.0 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 \\
\hline
\end{longtabu}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: long table had not to be inside float environment `table`. in it it lost its features to be braked over two or more pages.

Comment: nor should it be in a `center` environment,

Comment: And to fit the table to text width? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: And to fit the table to text width? @Zarko

Comment: @user151562, below you have two answers. both solve all your problems with long `longtabu`/`longtable`  ...

Answer (score 2):

- `longtable` had not be inside float environment `table`
- nor in `center` environment (it is default centered in text)
- if you prescribe table width than you should use `X` columns, otherwise columns are not equal spaced
- your table is not so high that it need to be braked over more package, however this is sensible, if you like to have some text before table (as is shown in mwe below)
- the use of `tabu`/`longtabu` can be problematic, package is not maintained and buggy

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, multirow, tabu}

\usepackage{geometry}% added
\usepackage{lipsum} % added for dummy text

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|p{4em}|p{6em}|*{9}{X[c]}|}
\caption{$E_{T}$ values}
\label{tab:table8}      \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\bfseries
                Percent Upgrade}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{\bfseries\centering
                        Length\newline (mi)}
        &  \multicolumn{9}{c|}{\textbf{Proportion of Trucks and Buses}} \\
    \cline{3-11}
    &   & 2\% & 4\% & 5\% & 6\% & 8 \% & 10 \% & 15 \% & 20 \% & 25\% \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{$E_{T}$ values}\\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\bfseries
                Percent Upgrade}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{\bfseries\centering
                        Length\newline (mi)}
        &  \multicolumn{9}{c|}{\textbf{Proportion of Trucks and Buses}} \\
    \cline{3-11}
    &   & 2\% & 4\% & 5\% & 6\% & 8 \% & 10 \% & 15 \% & 20 \% & 25\% \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{11}{r}{Continued on next page} \\*
\endfoot
    \hline\hline
\endlastfoot
$\leq 2$ & All & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5    \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{=}{$>2-3$}
    & $ > 0.00 - 0.25$  & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $> 1.00 - 1.50$   & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 1.50$          & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    \hline
\multirow{6}{=}{$>3-4$}
    & $> 0.00 - 0.25$   & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 1.00 - 1.50$   & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 1.50$          & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\
    \hline
\multirow{5}{=}{$>4-5$}
    & $> 0.00 - 0.25$   & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\*
    & $> 1.00$          & 5.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{$>5-6$}
    & $> 0.00 - 0.25$   & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 4.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 0.30 - 0.50$   & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\*
    & $> 1.00$          & 6.0 & 5.0 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5   \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{$>6$}
    & $> 0.00 - 0.25$   & 4.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.0   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 0.30 - 0.50$   & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 6.0 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5   \\*
    & $> 1.00$ & 7.0    & 6.0 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 4.0         \\
    \end{longtabu}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

- see, if you like to use of the package `booktabs` and removing vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, multirow, tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}% added

\usepackage{geometry}% added
\usepackage{lipsum} % added for dummy text

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {p{4em} p{6em} *{9}{X[c]} }
\caption{$E_{T}$ values}
\label{tab:table8}                      \\
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{=}{\bfseries
                Percent Upgrade}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{\bfseries
                        Length\newline (mi)}
        &  \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Proportion of Trucks and Buses}} \\
    \cmidrule{3-11}
    &   & 2\% & 4\% & 5\% & 6\% & 8 \% & 10 \% & 15 \% & 20 \% & 25\% \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{$E_{T}$ values}            \\
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{=}{\bfseries
                Percent Upgrade}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{\bfseries
                        Length\newline (mi)}
        &  \multicolumn{9}{c|}{\textbf{Proportion of Trucks and Buses}} \\
    \cmidrule{3-11}
    &   & 2\% & 4\% & 5\% & 6\% & 8 \% & 10 \% & 15 \% & 20 \% & 25\% \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{11}{r}{Continued on next page} \\*
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
$\leq 2$ & All & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5    \\
    \midrule
\multirow{6}{=}{$>2-3$}
    & $ > 0.00 - 0.25$  & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $> 1.00 - 1.50$   & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 1.50$          & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    \midrule
\multirow{6}{=}{$>3-4$}
    & $> 0.00 - 0.25$   & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 1.00 - 1.50$   & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 1.50$          & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\
    \midrule
\multirow{5}{=}{$>4-5$}
    & $> 0.00 - 0.25$   & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\*
    & $> 1.00$          & 5.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\
    \midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{$>5-6$}
    & $> 0.00 - 0.25$   & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 4.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0   \\*
    & $> 0.30 - 0.50$   & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\*
    & $> 1.00$          & 6.0 & 5.0 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5   \\
    \midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{$>6$}
    & $> 0.00 - 0.25$   & 4.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.0   \\*
    & $>0.25 - 0.50$    & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 0.30 - 0.50$   & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5   \\*
    & $> 0.50 - 0.75$   & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0   \\*
    & $> 0.75 - 1.00$   & 6.0 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5   \\*
    & $> 1.00$ & 7.0    & 6.0 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 4.0         \\
    \end{longtabu}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

which gives more "proffesional" looks of table:

[image]

Comment: +1. However, I think the use of the typographic minus symbol (`-`) to stand in for en-dashes (`--`) in the first two columns should be avoided.

Comment: yes, you are right. i just left what op already have. i will left to her/him to correct this or use your solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another pure-`longtable` solution. No vertical lines, only a few (but well-spaced) horizontal lines, and no use of **bold-facing** for the header material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal lines

\newcommand\mytab[2][l]{\smash{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}} #2 \end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} l c *{9}{c} @{}}
\caption{$E_{T}$ values}
\label{tab:table8}\\

\toprule
\mytab{Percent\\Upgrade} & 
\mytab[c]{Length\\(mi)} &  
\multicolumn{9}{c@{}}{Proportion of Trucks and Buses} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-11}
& & 2\% & 4\% & 5\% & 6\% & 8\% & 10\% & 15\% & 20\% & 25\% \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{11}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable, continued from previous page} \\
\toprule
\mytab{Percent\\Upgrade} & 
\mytab[c]{Length\\(mi)} &  
\multicolumn{9}{c@{}}{Proportion of Trucks and Buses} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-11}
& & 2\% & 4\% & 5\% & 6\% & 8\% & 10\% & 15\% & 20\% & 25\% \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{11}{r@{}}{Continued on next page} \\ 
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

$\leq 2$ & All & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{6}{*}{$>2$--3} &  0.00--0.25  & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 
1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& 0.25--0.50 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
&  0.50--0.75 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
&  0.75--1.00 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
&  1.00--1.50 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
&  $>1.50$ & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{6}{*}{$>3$--4} &  0.00--0.25  & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 
1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& 0.25--0.50 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
&  0.50--0.75 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
&  0.75--1.00 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
&  1.00--1.50 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
&  $>1.50$ & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{5}{*}{$>4$--5} &  0.00--0.25  & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 
1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& 0.25--0.50 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
&  0.50--0.75 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
&  0.75--1.00 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
&  $>1.00$ & 5.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{6}{*}{$>5$--6} &  0.00--0.25  & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 
1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 \\
& 0.25--0.50 & 4.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
&  0.30--0.50 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
&  0.50--0.75 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
&  0.75--1.00 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
&  $>1.00$ & 6.0 & 5.0 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{6}{*}{\phantom{5--}$>6$} &  0.00--0.25  & 4.0 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 
& 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.0 \\
& 0.25--0.50 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
&  0.30--0.50 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\
&  0.50--0.75 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
&  0.75--1.00 & 6.0 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 3.5 & 3.5 & 3.5 \\
& $>1.00$ & 7.0 & 6.0 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.0 & 4.5 & 4.0 & 4.0 & 4.0 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```